# bug in mobile using mouseenter and mouseleave event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

my checkbox needed to be tap twice to be checked in mobile because it's within an li which I apply mouseenter and mouseleave event. Any hack to deal with that problem?

Comment: Not so much a Hack but, Mouse enter and mousleave are both called onclick which is what a touch on ipad or other touch device is . Instead of using mouse enter and mousleave capture with onlcick instead, this will solve your problem. If you provide a jsfiddle or actual porblem I would be happy to help more thoroughly

Comment: you could also attempt detecting device type with a library such as modernizer and modify javascript based on device touch though this will be kind or buggy an a non-ideal solution

Comment: mouseenter and mouseleave is for desktop of course, what do you mean by by capture with onclick?

Comment: eg. if your are trying to replace a hover type behavior  use the click() handler for jqery http://api.jquery.com/click/ without an example of what your attempting to do it is hard to suggest a solution. I know of no way to disable the mousenter and leave events but redesigning the code will remove the problem in majority of situations

Comment: when you say `tap` do you mean you are on a mobile device? if so, take a look at this http://danielglyde.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/touchit-jquery-plugin-for-touch-events.html

Comment: @brendanmorrison imagine a todo list app with its li bind with hover event.. how would you solve that? if I use the conditional method, means the hover no longer work, and the app lose some functionality when the user is on mobile..

Comment: This may be a trade off your willing to make? if not you could try a responsive approach in which a screen size less then 1200px (currently 90%+ of desktop browsers in north america above this resolution so not guarantee on mobile) in which case add a test in javascript to find screen resolution (using `$(window).height()` or `$(window.width()` )and remove li.bind and instead display hover state with `$(li).click()` with an additional button to handle what a click event would trigger on desktop. This may not be ideal solution but is what makes good responsive design choices hard.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, the fix I came across (can't remember where) was:

```
var el = document.createElement('div'),
mouseDown= ('ontouchstart' in el)?'touchstart':'mousedown',
mouseUp= ('ontouchend' in el)?'touchend':'mouseup',
mouseMove= ('ontouchmove' in el)?'touchmove':'mousemove';
```

and then use these vars as the expected event

```
$(someSelector).on(mouseDown, mouseDown_TouchStart_Handler);
$(someSelector).on(mouseUp, mouseUp_TouchEnd_Handler);
$(someSelector).on(mouseMove, mouseMove_TouchMove_Handler);
```

Hope this helps